# element 0 is undefined on form post in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

I'm opening a query dialog box which has two query tabs in MVC application. both tabs loading different partial pages. I've form in one of tab. form validation works fine. I'm getting error $element[0] is undefined in jquery.validate.js @ line 806 **when there is no validation error in form**. I'm unable to understand whats issue. below is code:

```
    Include references in _Layout.cshtml:
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

Partial view which open in one of tab:
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateMediaCode", "MediaCode", null,
        new AjaxOptions
        {
            UpdateTargetId = "myMsg",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            OnSuccess = "mySuccess"
        }, new { @id = "myFormId" }
        ))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true) 
 }
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('#myFormId));
    }
</script>
```

any help would be appreciated. what's happing here?

Answer (score -1):

It is inside the `mySuccess` callback used as `OnSuccess` handler in your `AjaxForm` that you should call `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse` method, not inside a `document.ready`. You shouldn't have a document.ready handler inside a partial. You shouldn't have any javascript inside a partial by the way. JavaScript should be written in separate files. Partial views should contain only markup.

Comment: am still getting error even after moving $.validator.unobtrusive.parse to onSuccess. BTW, am getting error even this line is commented

Comment: I suppose that's because you have included the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` script **after** the jquery and jquery.validate script which obviously is wrong. Your scripts should be included in the correct order which is: 1. jquery, 2. jquery.validate, 3. jquery.validate.unobtrusive. Don't include scripts in your partial views.

Comment: am not expert in Jquery. not sure, whats happoing. I changed script order and removed jquery.validate. My main page started throwing errors. and if I don't exclude jquery.validate.unobtrusive from partial view, it doesn't perform validation.

Comment: You should not remove jquery.validate. The jquery.validate.unobtrusive script depends on jquery.validate.

Comment: $.validator.unobtrusive.parse statement returns 'undefined' in immediate window. any idea? Form validation works but it throws 'element 0 is undefined' when there is no error